# Why is the overflow not hiding the transition effect?

Tags: html, css

When I mouseover the button, the hover effect of the white background color transitions outside of the button and the overflow property doesn't work. The `overflow: hidden;` should display the effect inside the button.

```css
.button {
    flex: 0 0 auto; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #ffbb11; 
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button::before,
.button::after {
    background: #fff;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.button:hover {
    color: #ffbb11;
}

.button::after {
    height: 70px;
    left: -8%;
    top: 5;
    transform: skew(50deg);
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transform-origin: top;
    width: 0;
}

.button:hover:after {
    height: 60px;
    width: 325px;
}

.iconBtn{
    max-height: 85%;
    max-width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
        <a href="https://apply.sorensonvrs.com/secured_contact_support"><div class="button"><img src="http://beacon.svrs.com/asset/imgs/icon-techsup2.png" class="iconBtn">
        <div class="serv-name">TECHNICAL SUPPORT</div></div></a>
                </div>
      <div class="services">
            <a href="http://www.sorensonvrs.com/contact_customer_service"><div class="button"><img src="http://beacon.svrs.com/asset/imgs/icon-custserv2.png" class="iconBtn"> 
        <div class="serv-name">CUSTOMER SERVICE</div></div></a>

      </div>
```

See on **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/magnix2k/0969sfrc/)**

Comment: Your indentation is really bad. Please, fix it. I'll do my best to help after you fix it.

Comment: You mean the codes arent in order?

Comment: @ChristianLuneborg He's probably talking about how in your html, none of the elements line up with each other.

Comment: It was a copy/paste from my HTML file and I've done that many times and nobody said anything about it except Jorge Gonzalez.

Comment: @ChristianLuneborg Noone saying nothing not means that is good (look at the upvote, so I'm not the only one thinking this). As a protip from an experienced user to a newbie, keep your indentation clean. **Indentation is important.** Read this: https://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/formatting-and-indenting-your-html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing some `code`. Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0969sfrc/4/). You should add `position: relative;` in `button` `class`. Hope this will help!

Comment: Yeah, that works. The `html { box-sizing: border-box;}` wasn't needed so I removed it. When it transitions the black label text disappeared and you can see it through even there is not a CSS of `opacity: 0;`?

Comment: Nevermind about the `opacity: 0;` Its was on `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);` - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the final product you are looking for but you can try this

```
.button::before,
.button::after {
    background: #fff;
    content: '';
    position: relative;

}
```

relative instead of absolute

Comment: Your code didn't work. The effect of the white background to animate inside the button, but currently, its displaying outside of the button.